# cannot connect mysql server remote

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I cannot conect to Mysql server remotely, access granted to user from any host and mysql server is running. I can access locally using 127.0.0.1 but when I try to connect using machine's IP it gives me error "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.102 (10060)'". I searched a lot couldn't sort this problem.

Comment: Does your firewall permit the access?

Comment: how to check that? please

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @imsome1 `telnet mysqlhost 3306`

Comment: when I disable firewall I can connect but how do I enable firewall for MySql,thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoudh check foll steps

MySQL is listening on public IP (sounds like you've done)
MySQL is listening on standard port / you're connecting the same port it's listening to.
Is there a firewall running on the remote machine? (They usually are packaged standard in distros) Is the firewall configured to allow connections to that port?
If the remote machine is within another network, is there network address translation (NAT) going on between your connection and the end machine - if so, is it configured to allow the MySQL port through.
Is the my.cnf file configured to allow connections from anything other than localhost 127.0.0.1 IPs - although you'd more likely get a access denied response, than a cannot connect.

Comment: its firewall problem, thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

please check your mysql config file, disable

> bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Comment: you mean in my.ini file right? bind-address is not there. where I should add that in my.ini file

Comment: @imsome1 i mean you should disable `bind-address 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @imsome1 if you use windows, yes!

Answer (score 0):

first ping the server ip, if reply you can try this :
reconfigure mysql server instance , allow connect from remote machines